# Capture the div when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I want to capture a `div` element when clicked on it using jquery & HTML2Canvas library in an environment where I have multiple `div` of that same class name.

This is for a console page on which I want to give user an extra choice to capture the div or not, everyone just don't bother about the event listener here I'm using.

```js
$('.panel.panel-default', this).one("mouseenter", function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName("panel panel-default")).then(canvas => {
    //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  
    console.log(image);  
    window.location.href = image;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a> this is panel one</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a> this is panel two</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a> this is panel three</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actual result should be like when I click on the `this is panel one` the event will capture that div into the file.

Comment: what is this in $('.panel panel-default', this) ? You already have the target inside the event handler just use that, no need to use getElementsByClassName

Comment: use this context to tell which one triggered the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just pass the right context

```
  $('.panel-body').on("click", function () {
        html2canvas(this).then(canvas => {
            //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
            console.log(image);
            window.location.href = image;
        })
    });
```

Comment: thanks karthick.....thats perfect
just need to know 1 thing  in ``$(this)[0])`` what is the significance of [0] here...

Comment: I think i wrote it as an habbit you can use only "this" (which is the target element), $(this) is the jquery object of that element (inorder to get the element from the jquery object you do $(this)[0])